# How can I echo non-printable characters like spaces?

Tags: echo

If I have non-printable characters assigned to a variable, how can I echo them?

For example, if I have a variable `xyz` set to be two spaces and a tab, then if I do this:

```
:echo xyz
```

it just shows a blank line. I can't actually see the characters to which the variable has been set. Is there any way to get echo to visualize non-printable characters?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `strtrans()` function, which translates unprintable characters.

[strtrans()](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strtrans%28%29)

> The result is a String, which is {expr} with all unprintable
>                   characters translated into printable characters 'isprint'.
>                   Like they are shown in a window.  Example: 
>                           echo strtrans(@a)
>                  This displays a newline in register a as "^@" instead of
>                   starting a new line.

Answer (score 3):

I often add characters around like in `:echo '###'.xyz.'###'`. It's simple enough, and more readable, IMO, than `:echo split(xyz, '\zs')`

Comment: The problem is that the variable can have other things in it besides spaces. There are a lot of different unprintable characters. Also, if there are a lot of spaces, like say 15 of them, it is not easy to count them when you just have a swath of whitespace in the printout.

Comment: You have `strtrans()` for unprintable characters, or your can map the split list of characters to `char2nr()` to know their code => `:echo map(split(xyz, `\zs`), 'char2nr(v:val)')`